# How to detect a day of the week and then use it to change style

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 7 columns, each for 1 day of the week. (link to demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/pL3dbfok/9/)

I want that the column's background will change automaticlly as the page loads based on the day: If it is the day that is written on the column, it's background will turn gray. (ig. if it's saturday, the saturday column will change).
I tried this:

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
console.log(n)
if (n == 6) {
  document.getElementById("SAT").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
} else {
  document.getElementById("SAT").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id "SUN">Sunday</th>
    <th id "MON">Monday</th>
    <th id "TUE">Tuesday</th>
    <th id "WED">Wednesday</th>
    <th id "THU">Thursday</th>
    <th id "FRI">Friday</th>
    <th id "SAT">Saturday</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It worked when I made it a function, activated by a button, but when I tried it not in a function, wanting it to load automatically, it didn't work.

I am not familliar with js, so it is probably some stupid mistake by me.

Please, if possible, respond with js solution, not jQuery.

Comment: Your code does not work because there is is no `=` between the `id` & its value

Comment: Javascript is correct (although a bit convoluted in my opinion), the problem is a basic html mistake. Add "=" for IDs. See this https://jsfiddle.net/5y6dnLop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call your script code directly as you do here, your document might not have loaded completely, so it can't find the element by id. Try to run your code when the page has finished loading, like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
console.log(n)
if (n == 6) {
  document.getElementById("SAT").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
} else {
  document.getElementById("SAT").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by targeting the `cells` of the row by the appropriate index.

Rather than using inline style I would also just add a class and use a css rule for the background and whatever other properties you want

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();

document.getElementById("heading-row").cells[n].classList.add('current-day');
```

```css
.current-day{
  background:grey
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="heading-row">
  <th>Sunday</th>
  <th>Monday</th>
  <th>Tuesday</th>
  <th>Wednesday</th>
  <th>Thursday</th>
  <th>Friday</th>
  <th>Saturday</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "=" between id and its value.

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
console.log(n)
if (n == 6) {
  document.getElementById("SAT").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
} else {
  document.getElementById("SAT").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="SUN">Sunday</th>
    <th id="MON">Monday</th>
    <th id="TUE">Tuesday</th>
    <th id="WED">Wednesday</th>
    <th id="THU">Thursday</th>
    <th id="FRI">Friday</th>
    <th id="SAT">Saturday</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```